# How to search 3 values in located in 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to search for 3 values in 3 columns on one worksheet. I'm fairly new to vba and need some assistance please. I have 3 values on worksheet "Data" in columns C, D and E which I need to find on worksheet "First" in columns C,D and E. Column C is sorted in numeric order.

So far I have a code that finds the value of C1 on the "Data" worksheet, in column C on the "First" worksheet. It then copies the data of the first line on the "Data" worksheet and inserts it under the active cell found in column C on the "First" worksheet. If value is not found on "First" worksheet, the code pastes the line at the bottom of data on worksheet "First". The problem is, my code finds the first occurence of C1 on "First" worksheet and inserts the line from "Data" worksheet underneath the active cell, but then D1 and E1 is not in numerical order.

This is what I have:

```
Sub Blank1()

Dim c As Range
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("first")

Set c = Source.Range("C1")

Set c = Target.Range("C:C").Find(what:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("C1").Select

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    c = ActiveCell.Value

    Sheets("first").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Find(what:=c, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
       LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
       MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Select

Else
    Sheets("first").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Select


End If

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("first").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, 
    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("C1").Select


  End Sub
```

I expect to insert values numerically on "First" worksheet. I also want it to loop through all values in C column on "Data" Worksheet.

Comment: What's not working/happening?

Comment: Welcome to SO. A data example would be helpful. So you want to find 3 values in 3 diferent columns, and if they match, ¿what do you want to do then? Please, be more specific about your problem. Help the community to help you :)

Comment: Hi Foxfire And Burns And Burns. I basically want the values from "Data" sheet (C1, D1, E1) be inserted in  columns C, D and E on "First" sheet but columns C of "First" sheet should stay in numerical order. Hope this makes better sense. Code should loop until no data left on "Data" sheet.

Comment: Then, in that case, because C of "First" must stay in numerical order, just insert all data that meet your requirements, and then order the data of "First" based on values from column C. That way you could order the data in numerical order after insterting

Comment: Foxfire And Burns And Burns, i can not do it that way. All values that are the same in C, for example, all 1.25 in Column C is then selected with their corresponding Columns D and E. Those selected, are then sorted in descending or ascending order using either column D or column E. Reason why I can't just insert and sort data everytime. Data on sheet goes as far down as row 5400.